# Visual Basic 2010 - Transfer listview info to another listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm using the same form, and initial information is being loaded to the first listview from an Access db file.  My question is, how do I get a single row of data to transfer, including multiple sub items, when I doubleClick?   I've seen solutions in VB 2006 that apparently are no longer relevant for 2010.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be wanting to try something like this

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDoubleClick
    ListView2.Items.Add(ListView1.Items(0).Clone())
End Sub
```

HTH

Comment: That worked, but how do I let it know which row to copy?  When I input this code, no matter which row ai click, it only copies info from the first row (0)

Comment: Nm, I got it ...  intCurrentSong = ListView1.SelectedIndices(0).        ListView2.Items.Add(ListView1.Items(intCurrentSong).Clone()).         Thank you VERY much!

Comment: it gets copied by index, currently set to 0 `ListView1.Items(0)` if you want the selected one to be copied instead replace the "0" with `Listview1.SelectedIndices(0)` that will clone the first selected item

Answer (score 0):

I was almost desperate.
so this is my conclusion :

```
Private Sub lvatk2_DoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lvatk2.DoubleClick
    Dim line = lvatk2.SelectedIndices(0)
    lvpo.Items.Add(lvatk2.Items(line).Clone())
End Sub
```

I am using Visual Studio 2008, but it worked thought. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This Should Work

```
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDoubleClick
    ListView2.Items.Add(ListView1.Items(ListView1.SelectedItem.Count).Clone())
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working:

```
For Each item2c As ListViewItem In ListView1.SelectedItems
  ListView2.Items.Add(item2c.Clone)
Next
```